# SQL query Substitution

Tags: sql

I need to substitute the key and value in SQL

Example:

```
Key: ### to ###, My address ###
Values: 10,20,'Jaipur India'
```

**Output**:

```
10 to 20, My address Jaipur India
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Please _edit_ your question, and instead show us sample input and output in tabular form, each line indented by 4 spaces to format it as code.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I have a string '### to ###, My address ###', and 3 values in a separate table, I need to replace these value by key, my first value is 10 so the first key get replaced with 10, 10 to ###, My address ### and such

Comment: Please provide a small sample so we are clear on exactly what you mean. Appears like you can just split up the values and add them to the key, but i would like a small sample to verify everything works as intended

Comment: What dialect of SQL are you using - add a tag for that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Example to achieve your desired result in SQL Server could be as follows:

1. Create a SQL TableValued Function that does the string concatenation and returns the  new string.
2. Call it from the SQL query.

**SQL Function**

```
Create function [dbo].[GetMyAddressString]
(
@Key1  varchar(100) ,
@Key2 varchar(100),
@Key3 varchar(100)
)
returns varchar(400)
as
begin
    declare @str varchar(400)
    set @str = @Key1 + ',' + @Key2 + ' My address ' + @Key3
    return @str
end
```

**How to call this function?**

```
select dbo.GetMyAddressString('10','20','Jaipur India')
```

**Output**

> 10,20 My address Jaipur India

Note:
If you can share the context and some more details too in your question, you can get more appropriate answer

Comment: thanks for quick response, the string is dynamic, how I can achieve? and the values are stored in a table

Comment: This simple SQL should help you to get desired result out. I am assuming that you have 3 columns in table with the Key values you need. Select cast(Column_KEY1 as varchar(4)) + ' to ' + cast(Column_KEY2 as varchar(4)) + ', my addres ' + Column_[ADDRESS_KEY] From TABLE_NAME_HERE